# Confusion about diagonalizing metric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional real vector space and $g$ an inner product on $V$ (my notation is similar but different from the one of riemanniann geometry), one could write $g(v,w)=v\cdot w$, for all $v,w\in V$. If $\mathcal{A}=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is basis of $V$, then the matrix $g_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$ is symmetric and positive definite by definition of inner product.

Trough Grahm-Schmidt algortihm, one can construct an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{A}'=\{e'_1,\dots,e'_n\}$ from $\mathcal{A}$. We therefore have
$$g(e'_i,e'_j)=\delta_{ij}.$$
Now, if we consider $(g_{ij})$ as the matrix associated to a linear application on $V$ in the basis $\mathcal{A}$, one could change the basis from $\mathcal{A}$ to another basis $\mathcal{B}$ of eigenvectors in which it is diagonal. But in the orthonormal basis $\mathcal{A}'$, the matrix should be the identity, by definition. In particular, it is diagonal. By unicity of the diagonal form (except for permutations on the diagonal), the two diagonal form should match. We could therefore conclude that any matrix that represent a metric (matrix which is symmetric and positive-definite) has all its eigenvalues equals to one. This seems wierd, isn't it ?

Moreover, the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
defines a metric but manifestly have an eigenvalue which is 2. So this a counter-example.

My guess is that is has to two with the fact that a matrix associated to a linear application and a matrix which is associated to a metric aren't the same under change of basis. Indeed, the former is such that $Mv$ is the same in any basis and the later is such that g(v,w) is the same in any basis. In other words, one transforms like a $(1,1)$-tensor and the other like a $(2,0)$-tensor. In this sens, the basis transformation of a matrix associated to a metric doesn't necessarily preserve the eigenvalues of the matrix and there exists a basis in which the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
becomes the identity. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

They dont have the same change, the change associated to an inner product is $t^PAP$ and the change associated to a morphism is $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: But the matrix that diagonalize a symmetric matrix is orthogonal, so $P^T=P^{-1}$ and the transformation are the same don't they ?

Comment: @xpsf An orthogal matrix will diagonalize, but does not guarantee the elements on the diagonal are $\pm 1$.  To get them to $\pm 1$ you need to transform with a matrix which is not orthognoal.